# Imposing conditions on argument for a function definition

Tags: functions, function-construction, piecewise, rule

Suppose that I wish to use "Piecewise" to merge two different interpolating functions (obtained via a NDSolve of some ODE), defined over negative and positive arguments respectively, like:

```
rule1 = f -> InterpolatingFunction["stuff"]
rule2 = f -> InterpolatingFunction["other stuff"]
rule1and2[xcoord_] := Piecewise[{{rule1, xcoord < 0},{rule2,xcoord > 0}}]
```

with this, I can then define a function over the real line in one go:

```
myfunc[x_] = f[x] /. rule1and2[x]
```

Now, myfunc works well. The problem is when I want to use rule1and2 independently. For example, writing

```
rule1and2[-1]
```

gives the "left-hand side" of the rule as expected, but it is a bit misleading since
one gets the impression that one top of it, on also evaluates the interpolating function at that specific point, which is of course not the case.

Instead, I would like to define rule1and2 in such a way that:

```
rule1and2[left]
```

gives the "left-hand" rule and

```
rule1and2[right]
```

gives the right one, and possible outputs a specific error message if the argument is none of the above two.
This seems like an easy thing to do, but I am puzzled by how to do it?

Comment: Why can't you use `f[x_] := Piecewise[{{InterpolatingFunction["stuff"][x], x < 0}, {InterpolatingFunction["other stuff"][x], x > 0}}]`?

Comment: Hi. The reason is because I need to have the rules separately to plug them into other functions, which themselves depend on f. I suppose I could then define a new rule through the function f and go from there, but it seems a bit convoluted, to start from a rule, define a function, and then define a rule from it again.